# Xamarin Forms How to know when a call is currently taking place

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, phone-call

I am writing some code for a Xamarin Forms Android app which dials a phone number but I don't want to dial the number if the user is currently on a call(whether incoming or outgoing, it doesn't make a difference). I have researched a lot about the phone state but I can't find what I am looking for, unless I am applying it incorrectly. What I need is something like this:

```
if (NoCurrentCallIsTakingPlace)
{
    var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(string.Format("tel:{0}", PhoneNumber));
    var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCall, uri);
    Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.StartActivity(CurrentIntent);
}
```

The code to dial the number works but it's the the conditional statement/code to check the phone state that I am having a problem with. Please could someone help. Apologies if your need more info. Please let me know and I will provide it. Thank you.

Comment: I've never tried it, but I would expect that Android would not let you launch a new call if one was already in progress

Comment: I have tried it and it does. It cuts the original call off and tries to dial the new number

Comment: did you try using telephony manager to check if the phone is idle?

Comment: I did try but I couldn't get it to work. Do you know of a decent tutorial on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in native android you have the telephony manager to check what is the state of your device:

It has three states:

- **Idle:** when it's idle there is no call
- **Offhook:** when Off-hook it is in call
- **Ringing:** when Ringing

  ```
      var telephonyManagerService = (TelephonyManager)Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.GetSystemService(TelephonyService);
      var getCurrentState = telephonyManagerService?.CallState;
      switch (getCurrentState)
      {
          case CallState.Idle:
            //No call
              break;
          case CallState.Ringing:
            //Ringing 
              break;
          case CallState.Offhook:
            //On call
              break;
          default:
              break;
      }
  ```

Revert in case of queries

Comment: Hi. That did it perfectly. Thank you ever so much. I had tried so many different implementations but the first two lines solved it. Thank you once again.

Comment: Sure no problem always happy to help!